# Add header with custom User-Agent for every HTTP request

Tags: python, python-3.x, http-headers, urllib, user-agent

Is it possible to make python use a custom header with a specific User-Agent string for every HTTP connection when using urllib? In order that the following persists throughout the program and is added to every Request(), urllib.request.urlretrieve() and every other function that establishes an HTTP connection:

```
.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')
```

Or is it possible to change python's default User-Agent string from `Python-urllib/3.5` to `Mozilla/5.0` somewhere in its config files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the headers by using a `requests.Session`

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'my user agent'
response = session.get('http://google.com')
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid the requests library but whatever works.